# NiFi custom processors with shared references use the oldest version

Tags: java, jar, shared-libraries, apache-nifi

Been working with Nifi for a few months and noticed a dependency pattern that doesn't make sense, hopefully I can describe it clearly in case someone can shed light.

We've been prototyping several related but distinct custom processors, and these processors all use some common jar libraries.

For example,

Processors A and B use Library1

ProcessorA gets developed along with some of the code in Library1, build Library1 and then build ProcessorA for testing on the NiFi server, all is good

ProcessorB gets developed also with some of the code in Library1, and Library1 is rebuilt before building ProcessorB as a deployable nar

Then when testing ProcessorB on the NiFi server (including attaching to the process to step through) we find need to update relevant code in Library1

But, despite this update to the Library, ProcessorB still executes the old Libary code. A specific example was a for loop; it would still initialize int i = 1 after I changed the code to int i = 0.

Only after I did a clean/rebuild of ALL the processors (both A and B) did ProcessorB start recognizing the updated library code.

This is surprising since every processor nar package should have its own copy of the library jar, but it is acting like the earliest version takes precedent.

My question, finally: is this expected behavior when using shared code libraries among nar packages, or is there a better practice for architecting these? Or am I missing some wisdom from from the java/maven realm?

NiFi is v 1.8 but also experienced this in 1.5

Many TIAs

Comment: Could you confirm that: `1:` ProcessorA and ProcessorB are located in different nar bundles. `2:` Each nar contains the shared library in `META-INF\bundled-dependencies` but with different version. `3:` you don't have the shared library in the `nifi/lib` folder or somewhere else in classpath.

Comment: thanks for the reply. after working with this some more, it seems to be that my IDE is not always packing the nars as one would expect. specifically, in netbeans it seems if i use the "build with dependencies" option (goals = 'install') on all the dependencies and then on the processor project itself it seems to get everything in line